# How can I display the sum of certain columns of a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I do not understand javascript at all, I study as needed and I need help
I need to sum up the values of certain columns of a table, the rows of which are marked with a checkbox
For example: I mark the checkbox in two rows of the table and the sum of 3,4 and 5 columns is summed up and displayed somewhere on the page

Now I managed to find a piece of code that summarizes the value of the checked checkboxes in the form, and displays it on the page
I need help in replacing the part that receives the "value" of the input, with the one that gets the values of the cells in the stob = head of the table and sums them

**Here is this code**

```
var
    $form = $("#out_form"),
  $allCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox", $form),
  $sumOut = $("#checked-sum"),
  $countOut = $("#checked-count");
  
$allCheckboxes.change(function() {
    var
    sum = 0,
    count = 0;
    $allCheckboxes.each(function(index, el) {
    var 
        $el = $(el),
        val;
    if ($el.is(":checked")) {
        count++;
      val = parseFloat($el.val());
      if (!isNaN(val)) {
        sum += val;
      }
    }
  });
  $sumOut.text(sum);
  $countOut.text(count);
});
```

**HTML**

```
       <form action="" method="post" id="out_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}"/>
            <button type="submit">Check</button>
            <span id="checked-sum">0</span>
            <span id="checked-count">0</span>
            {%csrf_token%}
            <div class="table-view__container">
                <table class="table-view__table">
                    <tbody class="table-view__body">
                        {% for out in filter.qs %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label class="custom_Label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="{{ out.id }}">
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{out.date|date:"d(D).m.Y"}}</td>
                            <td>{{out.ts}}</td>
                            <td>{{out.pl}}</td>
                            <td>{{out.rem}}</td>
                            <td>{{out.comment}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```

It is necessary to sum these 3 columns:

```
...
<td>{{out.ts}}</td>
<td>{{out.pl}}</td>
<td>{{out.rem}}</td>
...
```

**UPD:**
I managed to display the amount with the checkbox active, but only the first line:

```
var
    $form = $("#out_form"),
    $table = $(".table-view"),
  $allCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox", $form),
  $sumOut = $("#checked-sum"),
  $countOut = $("#checked-count");
  
$allCheckboxes.change(function() {
  var
    sum = 0,
    count = 0;
  $allCheckboxes.each(function(index, el) {
    var 
        $el = $(el),
        val;
    if ($el.is(":checked")) {
        count++;
        $form.each(function () {
            var val1 = parseInt(document.querySelector(".ts", this).innerHTML,10);
            var val2 = parseInt(document.querySelector(".pl", this).innerHTML,10);
            var val3 = parseInt(document.querySelector(".rem", this).innerHTML,10);
            var total = (val1 * 1) + (val2 * 1) + (val3 * 1);
            sum += total;
            });
      if (!isNaN(val)) {
        sum += total;
      }
    }
  });
  $sumOut.text(sum);
  $countOut.text(count);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript can be confusing, its definitely not an easy programming language. Sorry for not using your code, but I think its overcomplicating things.

So mainly what this code does is to trigger a function using event handlers on all checkboxes, that sums or substracts from the `result` variable depending if they are checked or unchecked and then show the result in a `<span>` tag.

### Some key points

- I used `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')` to get all the checkbox elements.
- The following code is to create one event handler for each checkbox element:

```
boxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener("change", function() {
```

- The input checkbox element lives inside a `<td></td>`, so  `this.closest('td').nextElementSibling` is necessary to get the parent  tag and then with the help of `nextElementSibling` we can get the next `<td>` element of the table which has the value we need to sum or substract.

### Snippet

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'),
show = document.getElementById('showResult'), result = 0;

boxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener("change", function() {
       
       var firstElement = this.closest('td').nextElementSibling,
         secondElement = firstElement.nextElementSibling,
         firstValue = parseInt(firstElement.innerHTML),
         secondValue = parseInt(secondElement.innerHTML);
       
       var sum = firstValue + secondValue;
       this.checked ? result += sum : result -= sum;
       show.innerHTML = result;
    });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  width:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
span{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="box1" /></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="box2" /></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
<br>
<br>
<span>Result: </span><span id="showResult">0</span>
```

Comment: Tell me how I can use this with dynamic tables (data is inserted from the database)? I will not be able to assign a unique ID to each checkbox.

Comment: @WITT I actually coded it not dynamically because its easier to understand. I updated the code to be dynamic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to modify your code a bit to fit my table and it worked) I even managed to add a counter of checked boxes
Thanks!

Comment: That's awesome.. well done